# How to manage fixed bottom button on responsive design

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design

I am developing a responsive design for a website. The DA (director artistic) wants to put an action button at the bottom of the viewport.

And this button must be always displayed to the user.

I am applying a fixed bottom CSS style:

```
.mobile {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  width: 75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**On iOS**

The button is hidden when Safari's toolbar is displayed but it shouldn't be

[image]

And when the toolbar is hidden and the button visible, I can not click on it.
[image]

This toolbar has a different height depending on the iPhone version used.

Do you have some css tricks or any other idea to solve this case?

Comment: Is there any `z-index` rules applied to the button in your CSS?

Comment: On the container of the button, I have z-index: 2